# Issues with searching though tableview in Popover in iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, popover

I'm getting problem while searching though tableview in Popover.

After Search records are shown in table view, When I scroll it will show me the another table view without search bar and only that scroll the back one is fixed.

when I remove search text it works fine.

For iPhone it works fine. Problem occurs only when I show table view in Popover view.

(I wanted to add screen shot but I do not have that much of reputation :()

Please brows this [link](http://omni-bridge.net/test/tableviewios7.png) for screen shot

---

### Code

```
if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){

        newTimeEntry *timeEntryController = [[newTimeEntry alloc] initWithNibName:@"newTimeEntry" bundle:nil];
        timeEntryController.timeEntryDelegate=self;

        UINavigationController* addNavController;
        addNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:timeEntryController];

        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addNavController];

        timeEntryController.popoverObj=popoverController;

        [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f,520.0f)];

        [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}else{
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the related code (only the methods that we need to understand your setup please) and maybe you could host that screenshot (or many) on imgur or somewhere else ;) Sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean and a picture's worth a thousand words ;)

Comment: Added link to Screen shot

Comment: And how do you setup the popover, the tableview and its controller inside the popover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solved my problem :)

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller

willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

}